# ChartJS doesn't display any bars due to data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an array of integers fetched from the server, and I'm trying to display the info as a bar chart.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    const ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    const counts = [];
    const dates = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        drawChart()
        console.log("document ready");
        $("#date_form").submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            let url = $("#date_form").serialize();
            console.log("/data/?" + url);

            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/?" + url)
                .then((respone) => respone.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    var start_date = jQuery('input[name="start_date"]').val();
                    var end_date = jQuery('input[name="end_date"]').val();
                    let last_date = new Date(Date.parse(end_date));
                    let first_date = new Date(Date.parse(start_date));
                    let current_date = new Date();
                    current_date = new Date(first_date.getTime()- first_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);



                    <!--populates dates-->
                    while(current_date.getDate() <= last_date.getDate()){
                        current_date = new Date(current_date.getTime() - current_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
                        dates.push(current_date.toISOString().substr(0,10))
                        counts.push(0)
                        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+1)
                    }


                    data.forEach(function (object, index) {
                        if (dates.includes(object.pk)) {
                            let index = (element) => element = object.pk
                            counts[dates.indexOf(object.pk)] = object.fields.count
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(dates)
                    console.log(counts)
                    console.log("going to draw")
                    drawChart();
                });
        });
    });

    function drawChart() {
        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: dates,
                datasets: [{

                    data: counts,
                    backgroundColor: "#7eff41"
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
        // Global Options
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 15;
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#ff0058";
        dates.length = 0;
        counts.length = 0;
    }

</script>
```

Once I pass it on the data field of the ChartJS I get the following.

[image: bar chart error]

What's driving me crazy is the fact that if I pass data manualy (i.e [23,45,53,65], it works perfectly.

Tried  line chart with the fetched data and it worked perfectly, which means that it is not an async problem.

Comment: Is all values in counts array are all type integers? And have you check if it's an asynchronous problem?

Comment: You should call and pass `fetched data` to `drawChart` after your server or API gets back with the response data. You can use callbacks or promises as well!

Comment: I can confirm that all numbers are integers and it's not an async problem. please check my edit

Comment: @Volpym why dont you show the rest of your code , counts variable and where the drawChart is being called

Comment: @EugenSunic please find it inside the code section. I've updated it with my full script

Comment: Could you please post the contents of the console.log(counts) please..

Comment: @mkane  `[0, 150, 0, 0, 270, _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]`

Comment: Hi thanks for that the console output above does not look like an array of integers..